# WinEdt/miktex printing wrong alphabet

Tags: mathcal, mathbb

Suddenly today when I type `\mathcal{k}`, for example, in WinEdt and compile to MikTex, I get output: ∥.

I get similar strange characters for `\mathcal{}`,`\mathbb{}`,`\mathds{}` with any English character substituted in {}.

If I recompile old documents with `\mathcal{}`, etc., I have no problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

With the default font setup `\mathcal` only works for upper case letters. With `amsfonts` `\mathbb` only works with upper case, and `\mathds` is not defined at all.

Presumably your older documents were using a different font set that defined `\mathds` and possibly provided lower case versions of these alphabets.

Comment: Thanks!! Anyway to get lowercase for \mathcal{},et al.?